# Powershell scripting - replace text in files

Tags: powershell

Given these powershell functions below. I'm trying to replace the version text with another version that I specify. All my paths are correct, and I output both the current version and new version appropriatlely. When i go to replace them, the file indicates that it has changed, but no text was changed.

Alternately, I've found if i specify the exact current version as a string variable and bypass the Get-VersionXXX calls, it replaces the version without issues. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

```
function Get-VersionAndDateFromFile([string] $versionFile, [string] $versionString)
{
    if (-Not(Test-Path -path $versionFile))
    {
        return ""
    }
    else
    {
        #foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($versionFile))
        (Get-Content -Path $versionFile -Raw) | ForEach-Object {
            $line = $_
            if ($line.Contains($versionString))
            {
                if ($line.Contains(""""))
                {
                    $tokens = $line.Split('\"')
                    return $tokens[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ""
}

function Get-VersionOnlyFromFile([string] $versionFile, [string] $versionString)
{
    [string] $versionAndDate = Get-VersionAndDateFromFile $versionFile $versionStriong
    return VersionFromVersionAndDateString $versionAndDate
}

function Get-VersionFromVersionAndDateString([string] $versionAndDateString)
{
    if (!$versionAndDateString)
    {
        return ""
    }
    else
    {
        if ($versionAndDateString.Contains(" "))
        {
            $newTokens = $versionAndDateString.Trim().Split(" ")          
            return $newTokens[0]
        }
        else
        {
            return $versionAndDateString
        }
    }
}

function ReplaceTextInFile([string] $fullPath, [string] $oldString, [string] $newString)
{
    Write-Host "Old " $oldString
    Write-Host "New " $newString
    ((Get-Content -path $fullPath -Raw) -replace $oldString,$newString) | Set-Content -Path $fullPath
}
```

Calling code:

```
[string] $newVersionString = "1.2.3.4.6   09-16-2021"
[string] $currentVersionString = Get-VersionAndDateFromFile $pathToVersionFile "SW_VERSION"
ReplaceTextInFile -fullPath $pathToVersionFile -oldString $currentVersionString -newString $newVersionString
```

finally: file is a header file called Version.h

```
#define SW_VERSION "1.2.3.4.5 09-14-2021"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless explicitly redirected all output in a function is returned to the pipeline. The `return` command is redundant. As such, you're sending back two things in your function, first is the version number and second is an empty string (lines starting with >>>):

```
function Get-VersionAndDateFromFile([string] $versionFile, [string] $versionString)
{
    if (-Not(Test-Path -path $versionFile))
    {
        return ""
    }
    else
    {
        #foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($versionFile))
        (Get-Content -Path $versionFile -Raw) | ForEach-Object {
            $line = $_
            if ($line.Contains($versionString))
            {
                if ($line.Contains(""""))
                {
                    $tokens = $line.Split('\"')
>>>                 return $tokens[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }

>>> return ""
}
```

You convert the output to a string, and by all accounts it **looks** right, but if you look more closely you'll see there's a space after the date:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ">$currentVersionString<"
>1.2.3.4.5 09-14-2021 <
```

If we comment out the last `return` in that function the space goes away, and your replace should work fine.

```
function Get-VersionAndDateFromFile([string] $versionFile, [string] $versionString)
{
    if (-Not(Test-Path -path $versionFile))
    {
        return ""
    }
    else
    {
        #foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($versionFile))
        (Get-Content -Path $versionFile -Raw) | ForEach-Object {
            $line = $_
            if ($line.Contains($versionString))
            {
                if ($line.Contains(""""))
                {
                    $tokens = $line.Split('\"')
                    return $tokens[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }

#    return ""
}
```

To be honest, it would be much simpler to do this:

```
function Get-VersionAndDateFromFile([string] $versionFile, [string] $versionString)
{
    if (Test-Path -path $versionFile)
    {
        Get-Content -Path $versionFile -Raw | Where-Object{$_ -match "$versionString\s+""(.+?)"""} | ForEach-Object {
            $Matches[1]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I  had come across information describing the return pipe but didn't fully grasp what it was explaining. I've only been doing PS for a few days now, but it's clear that it's a different beast than the non-scripting languages.

Answer (score 1):

Run your Replace Function with these 2 added lines, as shown below...

$old = $oldString -replace '\s','\s';
$old = $old -replace '\s$';

You'll find you're capturing an extra space at the end of your OldString variable. Like so: **1.2.3.4.5\s\s09-16-2021\s**

The two lines fix the issue and it does the replace... or you can fix your Get-Version function to capture the correct string.

function ReplaceTextInFile([string] $fullPath, [string] $oldString, [string] $newString)
{
Write-Host "Old " $oldString
Write-Host "New " $newString

```
$old = $oldString -replace '\s','\s'; #replaces space with \s
$old = $old -replace '\\s$'; #removes trailing space at end of line

$old = $oldString -replace '\s','\s'; $old = $old -replace '\\s$'
((Get-Content -path $fullPath -Raw) -replace $old,$newString) | Set-Content -Path $fullPath
```

}